# Inaccessible object when compiling code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

I want to compile the [Rigi](http://www.rigi.cs.uvic.ca) source code but I get some error while compiling:

```
adt/object.h: At global scope:
adt/object.h:35:18: error: ‘class RigiObject RigiObject::RigiObject’ is inaccessible
adt/chararray.h:51:13: error: within this context
make: *** [cl_arcflags.o] Error 1
```

Here our two files.
**object.h**:

```
#ifndef OBJECTH
#define OBJECTH 1

#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef STREAM_H
#include <iostream>
#endif
#ifndef __STRING_H
#include <string.h>
#endif
#ifndef __STDLIB_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#ifndef _CCHEADER_H_
#include "CCheader.h"
#endif

extern char* indent_line(int);

class RigiObject;
typedef RigiObject* ObjectPtr;

#define Oberr(a) fprintf(stderr,"ERROR :: Generic Object Routine Called :: %s\n","a");

class RigiObject {
    public:
    RigiObject() {/*Oberr(RigiObject)*/;}
    ~RigiObject() {/*Oberr(~RigiObject)*/;}  

    // Routines that are really described by the Derived Classes
    virtual int Printout(int)  const
      {Oberr(printout); return (int) 0;}
    virtual unsigned int Hash() const  
      {Oberr(hash); return (unsigned int) 0; }
    virtual RigiBool isEqual(void* a) const
      {Oberr(isEqual); a = NIL; 
           (void) abort();
       return (RigiBool) RigiFalse;}  
    virtual void Delete_class(ObjectPtr) 
      {Oberr(delete_type);}
    virtual void* Create_class();
    virtual void* Duplicate_class();

};

#endif
```

and **chararray.h**:

```
#ifndef CHARARRAYH
#define CHARARRAYH

#ifndef ARRAYOBIDH
#include "array.h"
#endif
#ifndef CHARTYPEH
#include "chartype.h"
#endif

class CharArray;
typedef CharArray* CharArrayPtr;

class CharArray : public Array {
    int slot;
    public:
   // Routines to initialize and destroy the class.
    CharArray(unsigned int size = CLTN_DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    CharArray(const CharArray&);
    ~CharArray(); 

    // Functions that are Required to Use this Class as an Object

        // .... all routines the same as in Class Array.......

   // Routines that are required by a Collection class and derived classes
   // of Collections. [See Array Class for these routines.]

    virtual unsigned int size() const {return slot;}

        // .... all routines the same as in Class Array.......

   // Routines specific to this class
    void operator=(const CharArray&);
    RigiBool operator==(const CharArray&) const;
    void Create(char*);
    void Create(char*,int);
    void Create(int, char*);
    void Add(char*);
    void Add(CharType&);
    void Addob(RigiObject& ob)  
        {Array::Add(slot++,&ob);}
    void Append(char*);
    char* Concat(char);
    int FindIndex(char*);
    char* Remove() 
        {return ((CharTypePtr)Array::Remove(--slot))->string();}
    ObjectPtr Pop()
        {return (Array::Remove(--slot));}
    ObjectPtr Look(int i)
        {return (Array::At(i));}
    void Empty();
    virtual unsigned int Size() const
        {return slot;}
    char* Peek();
    char* At(int);
};

#endif
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: We have `class RigiObject { ... ` in line 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types `RigiBool`, `RigiObject` and `ObjPtr` are not available in *chararray.h*: you need to include *object.h* (plus whatever else defines `RigiBool` if *CCHeader.h* doesn't) -- similarly for `RigiBool` and `RigiFalse` in *object.h*

```
// somewhere at the top of chararray.h
#include "object.h"
```

*Note*: if you define virtual member functions in `RigiObject`, you should declare the destructor `virtual` as well

*Note*: You already have include guards *in* the `#include`d headers, no need to put them around the `#include` directives -- doing otherwise indicates (falsely in your case) that you are doing conditional compiling

```
//chararray.h
#ifndef CHARARRAYH  
#define CHARARRAYH  

#include "array.h"  
#include "chartype.h"  
...

//object.h
#ifndef OBJECTH   
#define OBJECTH

#include <stdio.h>   
#include <iostream>   
#include <string.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include "CCheader.h"   
...
```

Comment: I have a reference to `object.h` in other related files. I tried this before.

Comment: @Afshin - does `Array` derive from `RigiObject` or _CCheader.h_ include _chararray.h_ (possibly indirectly)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the type RigiBool in the declaration `RigiBool operator==(const CharArray&) const;` is not defined in one of the headers "array.h" "chartype.h" I think you should include the header containing definition of the type, and just to be sure the "object.h" too.
For cases where a header file uses values of class type variables (not pointers and references) it is recommended to include the headers that contain the class definition. Otherwise a simple forward declaration should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the little information but I would assume `RigiBool` is a derived class of `RigiObject`? When you now reference `RigiBool` in `chararray.h` it has to know the `RigiObject` base class but the `RigiObject` also needs to know about `RigiBool`. So you can't declare the base class without knowing the derived `RigiBool`. Try if forward declaring `RigiBool` in `object.h` helps to break the cycle.